# php curl module calling apache wsgi application

Tags: php, django, apache, curl, wsgi

I have setup a **django** application using **mod-wsgi** and apache. This application is tested and is working fine from the linux curl module. However when this application is being called by **php code through curl library** , i get the response as **"\x1f\x8b\b"** instead of the intended xml response.

Both the php and python applications are running on the same machine with different ports.

I have tried searching online for help but of no use as i am lacking the knowledge of how apache behaves in this situation.
Any help on this is appreciated. Please let me know if any further details are needed.

**Update:**
 I have narrowed down the problem to fewer parameters. I have completely eliminated the apache/django/wsgi application running on the port 8000. Now the php application running through port 80 just attempts (php curl) to retrieve a static text file through port 8000.

Even in this case the problem persists and the response string returned is still the same **"\x1f\x8b\b"** . One strange thing to note is, in both the cases (django application or static file) 
the **http response code returned is 200**. I tried loading a non-existent static file and noticed the response code to be 404 and the response still the same.

Apache is listening on both 80 and 8000 ports.

```
netstat -antp | grep "80"

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4348/python     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1183/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1183/apache2
```

So should be some issue with apache which i am missing. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The problem was basically the php curl call which i am using is getting the response in gzip format. This was not happening in the linux curl call as it automatically uncompresses the response before writing out.

I only had to disable the deflate module in apache.

```
a2dismod deflate
```

It worked like a charm. Now the static files and also the django/wsgi application are working smoothly.

Thanks.